# Does the Xbox One have backward compatibility for games on the original Xbox?

Tags: xbox-one, backwards-compatibility, xbox

I am aware about select Xbox 360 games being able to be played on the Xbox One, but what about the games for the original Xbox?

Comment: Short answer - No. They are only doing 360 games, at least that's the only thing they have announced at this point. [There is no mention](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/console/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq) of original Xbox games in the FAQ, only 360.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Understanding that this is an old question, I wish to update this thread for future reference.**
The Xbox head, Phil Spencer, has hinted that he wants original Xbox games to play on the Xbox One.
[image: Phil Spencer's Tweet]

Sources:
http://www.geek.com/games/phil-spencer-wants-xbox-one-to-play-original-xbox-games-1675442/
http://www.mcvuk.com/news/read/original-xbox-games-could-become-backwards-compatible-on-xbox-one/0173966

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No.**

Playing games for the original Xbox on the Xbox One is not supported, nor announced by Microsoft at the moment.